# Why does adding a WHERE statement (on a column with an index) to my query increase my run time from seconds to minutes?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

My problem is with this query in MySQL:

```
select 
    SUM(OrderThreshold < @LOW_COST) as LOW_COUNT,
    SUM(OrderThreshold > @HIGH_COST) as HIGH_COUNT
FROM parts
-- where parttypeid = 1
```

When the `where` is uncommented, my run time jumps for 4.5 seconds to 341 seconds. There are approximately 21M total records in this table.

My `EXPLAIN` looks like this, which seems to indicate that it is utilizing the INDEX I have on `PartTypeId`.

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key         key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      parts   ref     PartTypeId      PartTypeId  1       const       11090057
```

I created my table using this query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS parts (
    Id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    PartTypeId TINYINT NOT NULL, 
    OrderThreshold INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    PartName VARCHAR(500), 
    INDEX(Id),
    INDEX(PartTypeId),
    INDEX(OrderThreshold),
);
```

The query with out the `WHERE` returns

```
LOW_COUNT   HIGH_COUNT
3570        3584
```

With the `where` the results look like this:

```
LOW_COUNT   HIGH_COUNT
2791        2147
```

How can I improve the performance of my query to keep the run time down in the seconds (instead of minutes) range when adding a `where` statement that only looks at one column?

Comment: Is `parttypeid` indexed?

Comment: @nomistic `INDEX(PartTypeId),`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your accepted answer doesn't explain what is going wrong with your original query:

```
select SUM(OrderThreshold < @LOW_COST) as LOW_COUNT,
       SUM(OrderThreshold > @HIGH_COST) as HIGH_COUNT
from parts
where parttypeid = 1;
```

The index is being used to find the results, but there are a lot of rows with `parttypeid = 1`.  I am guessing that each data page probably has at least one such row.  That means that all the rows are being fetched, but they are being read out-of-order.  That is slower than just doing a full table scan (as in the first query).  In other words, all the data pages are being read, but the index is adding additional overhead.

As Juergen points out, a better form of the query moves the conditions into the `where` clause:

```
select SUM(OrderThreshold < @LOW_COST) as LOW_COUNT,
       SUM(OrderThreshold > @HIGH_COST) as HIGH_COUNT
from parts
where parttypeid = 1 AND
      (OrderThreshold < @LOW_COST OR OrderThreshold > @HIGH_COST)
```

(I prefer this form, because the `where` conditions match the `case` conditions.)  For this query, you want an index on `parts(parttypeid, OrderThreshold)`.  I'm not sure about the MySQL optimizer in this case, but it might be better to write as:

```
select 'Low' as which, count(*) as CNT
from parts
where parttypeid = 1 AND
      OrderThreshold < @LOW_COST
union all
select 'High', count(*) as CNT
from parts
where parttypeid = 1 AND
      OrderThreshold > @HIGH_COST;
```

Each subquery should definitely use the index in this case.  (If you want them in one row with two columns, there are a couple ways to achieve that, but I'm guessing that is not so important.)

Unfortunately, the best index for your query without the `where` clause is `parts(OrderThreshold)`.  This is a different index from the above.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
select SUM(OrderThreshold < @LOW_COST) as LOW_COUNT,
       SUM(OrderThreshold > @HIGH_COST) as HIGH_COUNT
from parts 
where parttypeid = 1
and OrderThreshold not between @LOW_COST and @HIGH_COST
```

and

```
select count(*) as LOW_COUNT, null as HIGH_COUNT
from parts 
where parttypeid = 1
and OrderThreshold < @LOW_COST
union all
select null, count(*) 
from parts 
where parttypeid = 1
and OrderThreshold > @HIGH_COST
```

Comment: The first one works perfectly. The union takes a little longer, but also returns the data faster than my original query. It seems my issue was that I forgot a condition in my `WHERE` statement.